# Calling a function with parameters in another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm calling a function in another one. Of course, this is easy, using [name].onclick=funcion. This works, but if I want with parameters, how can I do this?

An easy example: Where is "y" I want to pass "abc" but with bt.onclick=second with (abc) doesn't work and witout there isn't parameters.

```
function first(x){

var abc = document.getElementById(x);
var bt = document.createElement("button");
bt.onclick=second;
}

function second(y){

document.getElementById(y);
}
```

Comment: There is a way, but for that you should have value of `y` while attaching event listener. having a callback, and calling `second` function with `y` value along with `onclick` `event` param if required.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to pass "abc"

try

```
bt.onclick= function(){
   second(abc);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

- Invoke a `second` function with argument
- Return another function from `second`
- Inner function remembers the environment in which it is created hence `y` is known for `inner-function`

```js
function first(x) {
  var abc = document.getElementById(x);
  var bt = document.createElement("button");
  bt.onclick = second(WHATEVER_YOU_WANT_TO_PASS);
  //------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}

function second(y) {
  return function() {
    document.getElementById(y);
  }
}
```